# Virtual keyboard changes my page height

Tags: mobile, height, viewport, dimensions, virtual-keyboard

I'm developing a web app for mobile phones and i got a strange problem.
I have a simple page with a background image and an input field centered in the middle of the page.
The problem is whenever i click the input box and the virtual keyboard comes up, the background image and input field dimensions are recalculated according to the remaining page space.

The desired behavior is that the whole page will be pushed up.

relevant code (i'm developing with react, hence the weird names)

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">.location_input__LocationInputStyle___2cLQ9 {
        position: absolute;
        width: 85%;
        height: 10%;
        top: 45%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%);
        background-color: transparent;
        border-radius: 50px;
        border: 3px solid #ffffff;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #ffffff;

    }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">.home_page_container__HomePageStyle___2f5vW {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-image: url(86349e48855062e70072f79443fe0af6.jpg);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: 40% 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <div class="home_page_container__HomePageStyle___2f5vW">
        <input type="text" class="location_input__LocationInputStyle___2cLQ9" placeholder="Address">
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Related Images:

[The problem, when keyboard pops up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qdsJ.jpg)

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XS2vl.jpg)

P.S: after playing with the debugger a bit, i found out that if i set the height of my app container/body/html to a fixed pixel height it doesn't happen.
Yet it's not a good solution, because i want the height to be 100% of the viewport (so it will be compatible with all devices).

How do i fix it properly?

Comment: This is the app when the keyboard is hidden:
[app without keyboard](http://imgur.com/a/9bISr)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify min-height for the keyboard div.
You can also try giving the dividing the text part and keyboard part  in  `vh` (viewport height, like for `input div : 50vh,keyboard :50vh` ) instead of giving `height:100%;`.Please remove all other heights.